# Problem with Recursive CTE very long query plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression, database-performance

When I execute below query SQL run this plan and it took a long time to run it and it will not be over.

[QueryPlanLink](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1jkqk8W5)

I have 3 million records in #T table.

myCode:

```
;WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT NationalId,len(NationalId) as LenNationalId,CustomerType,FullDateInt,time,
         SUM(Price) as SUMPrice
        ,AVG(Price) as Price
        ,SUM(Volume) as  Volume
        ,SUM (sum([Volume])) OVER (PARTITION BY NationalId,len(NationalId) ORDER BY FullDateInt,[Time]) as SumVol
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NationalId,len(NationalId) ORDER BY FullDateInt,[Time]) AS rn
from #T as T1
group by NationalId,len(NationalId),CustomerType,FullDateInt,time

), rcte AS (
    SELECT *, Price AS Cost , cast(0 as decimal) as Profit
    FROM cte1 AS base
    WHERE base.rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT curr.*, Case when curr.Volume>0 Then ((curr.Volume *curr.Price) + (prev.Cost*prev.SumVol))/nullif(curr.SumVol,0) 
                        when curr.Volume<0 Then prev.Cost
                   End
    as Cost
    ,ISNULL(Cast (Case when curr.Volume<0 Then -1*(curr.Price-Cost)*curr.Volume End as decimal),0) as Profit
   
   FROM cte1 AS curr
  INNER  JOIN rcte AS prev 
    ON curr.NationalId = prev.NationalId  AND curr.rn = prev.rn + 1
)

Select * from rcte
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Is there any way to make it better?

Thanks

Comment: Doing such operation in temp table which cause tempdb contention is not a great idea. First of all prevent doing this with #table. Then add proper index on table to avoid Hash match component.

Comment: BTW, we can't search/expand or copy code from an image :) Please post sql as "text". Also, use something like https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ for sharing actual query plans.

Comment: First off, copy and paste your code in to the question as code. Second, it's somewhat unclear what the purpose of that SQL is - why are you using a recursive CTE?

Comment: I want to calculate each record with use Previous calculated record.

Comment: That image of a query plan is not a query plan - as above, provide the actual plan using [Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1jkqk8W5

Comment: "I want to calculate each record with use Previous calculated record." doesn't really clarify it much. That image of a query looks like you're trying to get a total price and quantity of each product sold based on whatever NationalId is? In which case, WHY the recursive CTF?

Comment: What's the point of `group by NationalId,len(NationalId)`? You'll never have two NationalIds that are the same... but different lengths.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any kind of covering index on the temp table.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewCorrigan for your answer , For Example In This Excel File I Want Calculate Cost And Profit Column, with Use Formula in excel cell : [link](https://file.io/TDin640aDRLV) , This is only for one account I have 3 million Account and I want Calculate Cost And profit for Each Account Per Day , Like That Formula In Excel Cell On Column Cost And Profit.

Comment: That link is to a deleted file...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning , Thanks Bro For Answer me,Sorry,My data is very dirty, So I Have It, That Column Type is nvarchar and has some character that causes me,I have two NationalIds that are the same, but different lengths....

Comment: @mortezazakeri they're not the same then. One has whitespace and one doesn't

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan (https://www.mediafire.com/file/iari0fb3o2f1tnk/dara_-_Copy.xlsx/file)

Comment: Also, what is FullDateInt? And why are you grouping on a time?

Comment: @mortezazakeri just copy and paste the excel formula into the question

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan FullDateInt Like a Date, I Have Different Price For each Time On a Date , Cost for Positive Volume is =(SumAllPreviousVolume * Previous Cost + Current Volume * Current Price)/SumAllCurrentVolume and For Negative Volume Is Previous Record Cost

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to take a serious look at how the data is stored before you even think about how to speed up the query. Good data doesn't necessarily breed good queries; but bad data breeds bad queries.

Answer (score 1):

I Change My Query like below And Everything is Done. Thanks For All.

```
SELECT NationalId,len(NationalId) as LenNationalId,CustomerType,FullDateInt,time,
         SUM(Price) as SUMPrice
        ,AVG(Price) as Price
        ,SUM(Volume) as  Volume
        ,SUM (sum([Volume])) OVER (PARTITION BY NationalId,len(NationalId) ORDER BY FullDateInt,[Time]) as SumVol
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NationalId,len(NationalId) ORDER BY FullDateInt,[Time]) AS rn
into #TCTE from #T as T1
group by NationalId,len(NationalId),CustomerType,FullDateInt,time



;With rcte AS (
    SELECT *, Price AS Cost , cast(0 as decimal) as Profit
    FROM #TCTE AS base
    WHERE base.rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT curr.*, Case when curr.Volume>0 Then ((curr.Volume *curr.Price) + (prev.Cost*prev.SumVol))/nullif(curr.SumVol,0) 
                        when curr.Volume<0 Then prev.Cost
                   End
    as Cost
    ,ISNULL(Cast (Case when curr.Volume<0 Then -1*(curr.Price-Cost)*curr.Volume End as decimal),0) as Profit
   
   FROM #TCTE AS curr
  INNER  JOIN rcte AS prev 
    ON curr.NationalId = prev.NationalId  AND curr.rn = prev.rn + 1
)

Select * 
into #TFinal from rcte
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: So what did you change? Removed the temp table and moved the query into the CTE?